# uploading file on secured FTP over https protocol c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ftps

I have to upload and download files on FTP with HTTPS. 
If I am thinking right I have to use HTTPWebRequest class since the ftp is using HTTPS protocol.

Now I'm trying to download a file but all the response stream I'm getting is just the "virtual  user 'XXX' logged in".

May be I'm not setting correct method type or something else is going wrong.

```
 WebRequest ftp1 = HttpWebRequest.Create(u1);
            ftp1.PreAuthenticate = true;
            ftp1.Credentials = netCred;

            ftp1.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)ftp1.GetResponse();            
                remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                localStream = File.Create("c:/TEST1.txt");
                int bytesProcessed = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;

                do
                {
                    // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
                    bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Write the data to the local file
                    localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    // Increment total bytes processed
                    bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                } while (bytesRead > 0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
      finally
      {
        // Close the response and streams objects here 
        // to make sure they're closed even if an exception
        // is thrown at some point
        if (response != null) response.Close();
        if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
        if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
      }
```

Comment: I have added basic code. I've just started learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not using HTTPS; it's using FTPS (or possible SFTP). The `FtpWebRequest` class supports explicit FTPS by setting the `EnableSsl` property to `true`.

If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to use a third-party component. Have a look at the suggestions on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842186/does-net-ftpwebrequest-support-both-implicit-ftps-and-explicit-ftpes).

Comment: I tried using with FTPWebrequest but it failed because of URL I provide i.e. HTTPS://secureftp.abc.com.

Comment: Richard is right, I think you need to clarify with someone that providing you the URL if that's FTP(Secure) or Http(Secure).

Comment: When you have a FTP over HTTPS (HTTP with SSL), what should it be called?

Comment: There's no "FTP over HTTPS" protocol. You can either have FTP over SSL, which is FTPS, or SSH File Transfer Protocol, which is SFTP. http://www.eldos.com/sbb/sftp-ftps.net/ftps-vs-sftp.php

Comment: You must be right but I'm using a site to upload/download files over HTTPS. As I have given the part of URL earlier too... https://secureftp.abc.com. I have read many blogs and articles about FTPS and SFTP but my vendor guidleines is confusing me.

Comment: I still don't know how to use that URL with FTPWebRequest.

Comment: You cannot use an HTTPS URL with the `FtpWebRequest` class; you will have to use an FTP URL for FTP, or an `HttpWebRequest` for HTTPS. From the description of the problem, you're connecting to an FTP server, so you'll need to use an FTP URL.