# The underlying connection was closed. The server committed a protocol violation

Tags: c#, ssl, ftpwebrequest, filezilla, ftps

I am trying to get the directory list of a FTPS FileZilla server using the code below :

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertificate);
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

I got an exception when `FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse()` is executed :

> the underlying connection was closed. The server committed a protocol
>   violation.

When I switch to normal FTP connection. Everything works correctly.

Did I miss something to establish this FTPS connection ?
thanks for help

Comment: Do you have access to the Filezilla Server ? Are you sure the certificate is valid ? Did you configure it properly to use **explicit FTPS**

Comment: Yes I have access to the server. The certificate is also valid and the explicit FTPS is checked. I am using port 990 that refers to implicit SSL/TLS connection. Is it supported in FtpWebRequest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Implicit FTPS**  is **not** supported by the `FtpWebRequest` class (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842186/does-net-ftpwebrequest-support-both-implicit-ftps-and-explicit-ftpes)).

When `EnableSsl` is set to true, it actually triggers an `AUTH TLS` command to the server, asking to start an *Explicit* FTPS session.

In your case, you have to configure Filezilla Server to use Explicit FTPS. The procedure is documented on [Filezilla Wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTPS_using_Explicit_SSL/TLS_howto_%28Server%29)

Comment: that's true. I will consider try 3rd party libraries to use both explicit / implicit FTPS session. Thanks for help.

Comment: I will... Thanks again for support and help. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same problem but for uploading a file, on ftpWriter.Close().
Also, I was unable to do a GetRequestStream after a successful PrinWorkingDirectory for example.

The problem seems to be a "Expect: 100-continue" in the post - while I didn't quite checked this, the problem is somewhere there.

I've tried every solution found on the internet : changing the KeepAlive to true, adding to the App.Config file

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Nothing really worked.

I've spend a lot of time and trying different other third party libraries (idea I didn't like too much), until finally I came on a code that used the same classes and method but worked !!
After analyzing the code, I've finally figured out : the code targeted .NET Framework 2.0 while my code was targeting .NET Framework 4.5.
I seems that Microsoft did a little bug while passing from Framework 3.5 to Framework 4.

As it's not a solution to convert your new projects to target an old framework, you can create a dll for the FTP operations, pointing to the 3.5 .NET Framework, or, you can use third party libraries.

I'm maybe a little bit late, but it will probably help other frustrated developers on this matter, in the future.

Comment: If this is a bug in the client, I wonder why it only seems to happen when connecting to filezilla server? My code works fine with other servers

Answer (score 1):

This is the time to migrate from ftp to sftp!
you can follow to, this code reference:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using System.IO;
     private void UploadFileToSFTP()
            {
                try
                {
                    String sourcefile = @"C:\path\file.txt"; 
                    String host = @"000.000.000.0"; 
                    String username = @"usename"; 
                    String password = @"password"; 
                    int port = 22;
                    string destinationpath = "/var/www/html/path/public/destinationfolder";
                    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
                    {
                        client.Connect();
                        client.ChangeDirectory(destinationpath);
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                            client.UploadFile(fs, Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));
                        }
                    }
        }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

hope it would be helpful.
Thank you!