# Azure devops pipelines, inspect ftp traffic during release

Tags: c#, azure-devops, pipeline

Is there a way to log detailed ftp traffic from microsoft hosted agent?
In my case, when running ui tests in release pipeline, screenshoots are uploaded to ftp server.
It worked fine for few weeks unitl yesterday when I started getting following errors:

[image]

There was no change on the ftp server side and in c# code used for uploading ftp files.
Uploading files still works fine when i run tests locally and this issue happens only when they are run from pipeline, so I thought about comparing network traffic, looking for some clues.

Comment: Can't you add some logging to your tests? Log the ftp address and capture exception message etc.

Comment: if it's an FTP upload then why do you want HTTP logs?

Comment: @ADyson yes, my mistake I need ftp logs. I've updated description

Comment: @tubakaya, i have logs but they contain company data so I can't attach them to this post/question. The ftp address is fine, as well as credentials, the only exception is the one from screenshoot in the description

Comment: The exception is about the protocol, so I would check whether anything changed with settings. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278782/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation. There is also a post that suggests not to use the system.net.ftpwebrequest and instead to use alternatives, see here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-5.0

Comment: Hi @AdamStawarek. You could refer to the method in the answer and collect the ftp traffic log. On the other hand, since it could work on your local machine, you could also use the [Self-Hosted Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) and check if it could work.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT  sorry for late response. In next week I will get funds in aws  to create virtual machine, which i plan to use also as pipeline agent instead of default one hosted by Microsoft, so my orginal problem should resolve itself.
Still your anwser is great, and probably will be of great help to me or others in the future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to log detailed ftp traffic from microsoft hosted agent?

You could try to use the [network tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) to collect the Ftp traffic log.

You could add the configuration in the config file (e.g. web.config , app.config).

For example: To collect the `FTPWebRequest` and `FtpWebResponse` information, you could use `system.net`.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Information"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Then it will create a network.log file.

Since you are using the **Microsoft-Hosted agent**, you could determine the file location and use the `Publish Build Artifacts task` to upload the file as build artifacts.