# PowerShell FTPS upload fails with "System error."

Tags: powershell, ssl, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftps

## The problem:

A client requires that we upload extracted data from our system to their box.com platform, rather than our normal SFTP utility. I have box.com credentials, and am aware they require FTPS not SFTP, and require passive mode. I've cribbed a fragment from [ThomasMaurer's Powershell FTP Upload and Download script](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/11/powershell-ftp-upload-and-download/). Powershell version on my server is 4.0

## Code fragment is:

```
#config 
$Username = "username@host.com"
$Password = "redactedpassword"
$LocalFile = "C:\path\to\my\file.csv"
$RemoteFile = "ftp://ftp.box.com:990/file.csv"
#Create FTPWebRequest
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($RemoteFile)
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$FTPRequest
$FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
$FTPRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)
$FTPRequest.UseBinary = $true
$FTPRequest.UsePassive = $true
#read file for upload
$FileContent = gc -en byte $LocalFile
$FTPRequest.ContentLength = $FileContent.Length
#get stream request by bytes
$run = $FTPRequest.GetRequestStream()
$run.Write($FileContent,0,$FileContent.Length)
#cleanup
$run.Close()
$run.Dispose()
```

## The error(s):

```
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "System error." At C:\path\to\my\powershellscript.ps1:28 char:1
+ $Run = $FTPRequest.GetRequestStream()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: () [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebException
```

I also get downstream errors on calling the `$FileContent.Length` property and `$run.close` and `$run.dispose()`.

Has anyone successfully automated to box (specifically) or to a passive implicit-ssl using only PowerShell 4.0 commands, and do you have a solid pattern I could reuse?   Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm uploading files with a derived version of [System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), which supports FTP over TLS. This can easily be achieved by embedding C# code in PowerShell:

```
$typeDefinition = @"
using System;
using System.Net;
public class FtpClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address) as FtpWebRequest;
        ftpWebRequest.EnableSsl = true;
        return ftpWebRequest;
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $typeDefinition
$ftpClient = New-Object FtpClient
$ftpClient.UploadFile("ftp://your-ftp-server/yourfile.name", "STOR", "C:\YourLocalFile.name")
```

Comment: This worked after several other documented fixes did not, thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @h0r41i0 solves the problem by using `WebClient`. But as the `WebClient` internally uses `(Ftp)WebRequest`, it cannot be the solution on its own.

I'll assume that the "System error" occurs because either OP is trying to connect to a secure port (990) with an insecure connection.

Or because the file is too large and the OP code tries to read it whole to memory:

```
$FileContent = gc -en byte $LocalFile
```

In either case, there's no reason to give up on `FtpWebRequest`. Just use a secure connection ([`FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl)). And an efficient way to feed the data from the file to the FTP stream, for example [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto):

```
$request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
$request.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
$request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile 
$request.EnableSsl = $True

$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip")
$ftpStream = $request.GetRequestStream()

$fileStream.CopyTo($ftpStream)

$ftpStream.Dispose()
$fileStream.Dispose()
```

For other options, see [Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867385/850848#46582183).

Though note that .NET framework does not support implicit TLS (what is typical use of 990). Only explicit TLS. But support for the explicit TLS is more common ayway. See [Does .NET FtpWebRequest Support both Implicit (FTPS) and explicit (FTPES)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842186/850848#44756668)

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to be useful to original questioner, but I found this other answer did the trick for me: [Cyril Gupta's answer to Upload files with ftp using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485696/537243)

Here is my revised edition, including URL encoding (since the box.com usernames are email addresses which include the "at sign"):

```
## https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485696/537243
## User comment complains can't turn off passive mode, 
## but that is exactly what we want here!
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") | Out-Null

# config 
$Username = "foo@bar.com"
$Password = "s3cr3tpAssw0rd"
$Servername = "ftp.box.com"

# This is what we need URI it to look like:
#   ftp://foo%40bar.com:s3cr3tpAssw0rd@ftp.box.com/
$baseURI = "ftp://$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Username)):$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Password))@$($Servername)"

$LocalFile = "C:\tmp\to_upload\data.csv"
$RemoteFile = "date.csv"
$ftpURI = "$($baseURI)/$($RemoteFile)"

Write-output "ftp uri: $($ftpURI)";

$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient;
$ftpURI = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftpURI; #"convert" it
$webclient.UploadFile($ftpURI, $LocalFile);

Write-output  "Uploaded $($LocalFile) ... "; # of course since we didn't use try/catch or other error dectection this is a bit presuming.
```

Also should note this example uses plain FTP, not FTPS or SFTP.