# Connect to FTPS with proxy in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftps

My below code works perfectly fine in my computer without proxy. But in client server they need to add proxy to the FTP client (FileZilla) to be able to access the FTP. But When I add proxy it says

> SSL cannot be enabled when using a proxy.

**FTP proxy**

```
var proxyAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyAddress"];
WebProxy ftpProxy = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyAddress))
{
   var proxyUserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUserId"];
   var proxyPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyPassword"];
    ftpProxy = new WebProxy
    {
        Address = new Uri(proxyAddress, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUserId, proxyPassword)
    };
 }
```

**FTP connection**

```
var ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpAddress);
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                            username.Normalize(), 
                            password.Normalize()
                         );

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
   (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
//ftpRequest.Proxy = ftpProxy;
var response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Does this connect with a regular ftp client?

Comment: @Saruman yes it does

Answer (score 3):

.NET framework indeed does not support TLS/SSL connections over proxy.

You have to use a 3rd party FTP library.

*Also note that your code is not using "implicit" FTPS. It's using "explicit" FTPS. [Implicit FTPS is not supported by .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842186/850848) either.*

---

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), you can use:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
    FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit, // Or .Implicit
};

// Configure proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "proxy");

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    var listing = session.ListDirectory(path);
}
```

For the options for [`SessionOptions.AddRawSettings`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_addrawsettings), see [raw settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*