# using ftps (ftp over ssl) with ftpwebrequest class

Tags: c#, webrequest, ftpwebrequest, system.net

For a project, we need to communicate with an FTP Server over SSL (ftps)

I wrote the following code:

```
var ftpRequest         = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServer);
ftpRequest.EnableSsl   = true;
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
ftpRequest.Method      = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
var response           = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
var streamReader       = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var directories        = new List<string>();
```

When executing the example I get the following exception.

> SSL cannot be enabled when using a proxy.

At our company, we are behind a firewall a proxy, but that should not avoid the communication because e.g. over the windows explorer I can connect to the Server.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect using TLS/SSL over proxy. 
Looks like your question is a duplicate to this one [Connect to FTPS with proxy in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004666/connect-to-ftps-with-proxy-in-c-sharp)  which is already answered

Hope it helps

Comment: If its a duplicate, its more common to flag the question as a duplicate. unless you are adding more information and content, just a heads up