# C# FTP behind Proxy with FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, proxy, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I try to connect to an FTP-Server (Which is accessed over the Internet). My Company-Network is behind a Proxy, so I have to go through that somehow.

I've tried lots of things:

- [Getting Informations](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a3cca15-c307-4cc6-b5f5-bf3744960b6f/ftp-client-connecting-ftp-server-behind-a-proxy-server?forum=netfxnetcom)
- [Many SO-Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004666/connect-to-ftps-with-proxy-in-c-sharp)
- [Examples](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/ftp-klasse-fuer-c/1548)
- [And many more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298922/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp-in-c)

What I found out is, that the FtpWebRequest-Class doesn't support FTP-Upload behind Proxy (I guess to solve that I'll try the TCP-Client, but first things first) but it should support a Direcotry-List etc.

Nothing seems to work. According to my Network-Administrator, the Proxy-address is httpname.gr.ch with port 8080, but after I checked out the FileZilla-Settings there is another Proxy: ftpname.gr.ch:2121 so I assume that this one is the one I haven't get something to run properly.

I was only able to get a WebRequest with Proxy to run without an exception (no FTP). Here is the code-snippet that worked with the http-proxy:

```
        WebProxy a = new WebProxy("httpname.gr.ch:8080", true);
        a.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        WebRequest b = WebRequest.Create("https://www.heise.de/ct/hotline/Proxy-mit-Name-und-Passwort-316900.html");
        b.Proxy = a;

        WebResponse c = b.GetResponse();

        StreamReader d = new StreamReader(c.GetResponseStream());

        d.ReadToEnd();
```

However after I was able to get out of our network, I tried to read the FTP-Directory (which should work with Proxy). Here is my code-snipped to Check the Connection:

```
    public void CheckConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            WebProxy a = new WebProxy("ftpname.gr.ch:2121", true);
            a.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            FtpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
            FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + this.Adress));
            ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.User, this.Password);
            ftpWebRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpWebRequest.Proxy = a;

            //Als Methode muss ListDirectory gewählt werden!
            ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

            WebResponse webResponse = ftpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        }
    }
```

When I try to run that, I get this Error: "*The server has run a protocol violation.. Section=ResponseStatusLine*".

If I try without Proxy (ftpWebRequest.Proxy = null;), I get this Error: "*The Underlying Connection Was Closed. Could Not Establish Trust Relationship with Remote Server.*".

If I try with the http-Proxy, this is the Error: "*The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request*".

Everything I tried was stopped at "*ftpWebRequest.GetResponse();*".

Does anyone have an idea or a hint what or where the problem is? Am I totally wrong? Please help me. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is the Filezilla Log (German):

```
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Verbinde mit host über FTP-Proxy
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Auflösen der IP-Adresse für ftpname.gr.ch
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Verbinde mit ip:port...
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Verbindung hergestellt, warte auf Willkommensnachricht...
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 220 Frox transparent ftp proxy. Login with username[@host[:port]]
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: AUTH TLS
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 530 Please login with USER first
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: AUTH SSL
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 530 Please login with USER first
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Unsicherer Server; er unterstützt kein FTP über TLS.
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: USER user@host@ftp
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 331 User user@host OK. Password required
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: PASS ************
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: SYST
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: FEAT
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 502 Command not implemented.
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Der Server unterstützt keine Nicht-ASCII-Zeichen.
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Angemeldet
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Status: Empfange Verzeichnisinhalt...
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: PWD
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Antwort: 257 "/" is your current location
2018-07-24 13:34:35 580 1 Befehl: TYPE I
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Antwort: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Befehl: PASV
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Antwort: 227 Entering Passive Mode (193,247,16,24,103,35)
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Befehl: LIST
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Antwort: 150 Accepted data connection
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Antwort: 226-Options: -a -l 
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Antwort: 226 48 matches total
2018-07-24 13:34:36 580 1 Status: Anzeigen des Verzeichnisinhalts für "/" abgeschlossen
```

Here is the Program-Log (With ftpname.gr.ch as Proxy, like Filezilla):

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] FtpWebRequest#7746814::.ctor(ftp://host/)
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] Der aktuelle Betriebssysteminstallationstyp ist "Client".
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] FtpWebRequest#7746814::GetResponse(Methode = NLST.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] Associating HttpWebRequest#54246671 with ServicePoint#63840421
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] Associating FtpWebRequest#7746814 with HttpWebRequest#54246671
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] Associating Connection#59408853 with HttpWebRequest#54246671
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] Connection#59408853 - Die Verbindung von hostip:port mit targetip:port wurde hergestellt.
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] Associating HttpWebRequest#54246671 with ConnectStream#56152722
System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] HttpWebRequest#54246671 - Request: GET ftp://username/ HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [7264] ConnectStream#56152722 - Header 
{
Host: host
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
} werden gesendet.
System.Net Error: 0 : [7264] Exception in HttpWebRequest#54246671:: - Der Server hat eine Protokollverletzung ausgeführt.. Section=ResponseStatusLine.
System.Net Error: 0 : [7264] Exception in HttpWebRequest#54246671::GetResponse - Der Server hat eine Protokollverletzung ausgeführt.. Section=ResponseStatusLine.
System.Net Error: 0 : [7264] Exception in FtpWebRequest#7746814::GetResponse - Der Server hat eine Protokollverletzung ausgeführt.. Section=ResponseStatusLine.
   bei System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

**Solution**

I tried many possibilities (thanks to [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) for his help) and finally I made it trough the proxy to the FTP-Server :)

The trick is to have an FTP-Proxy (what I do have, as it's written in my question). You can check if it works with the command line and ftp.exe (Windows):

```
ftp.exe
open proxyadress port <- if it is not an FTP-Proxy, nothing happens <- crtl+c
ftpusername@host <- Because special domain and stuff I had to do: ftpusername@host@webhost
ftppassword <- It will not be displayed 
230 OK. <- Success!
```

After I was able to access the FTP-Server behind a Proxy from my command line I could try the FtpWebRequest-Class to do the same and it worked:

```
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftpproxy:proxyport");
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser@ftphost@webhost", "ftppassword");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.EnableSsl = false;
    request.UsePassive = true;

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("The content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
```

Comment: Ah now I understand, thank you :)