# The ftpes:// URI prefix is not recognized by FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftps

I have an FTP domain that I must to upload file txt to its FTP server the FTP domain looks like `ftpes://domain.com`, I never see the `ftpes` before, but when I upload by FileZilla it works success upload, but if I using my this code

```
FtpWebRequest ftpClient = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPdestination+ i + ".txt");
ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass);
ftpClient.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
ftpClient.EnableSsl = true;
ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(server+dtm+"_"+i+".txt");
ftpClient.ContentLength = fi.Length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
int bytes = 0;
int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
while (total_bytes > 0)
{
    bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
}
fs.Close();
rs.Close();
FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpClient.GetResponse();
uploadResponse.Close();
```

The error message is

> URI prefix not recognized

Please help me to solve my case.

Answer (score 4):

`ftpes://` is not a standard protocol prefix. But it is recognized by *some* FTP clients to mean *"Explicit FTP over TLS/SSL"*.

With `FtpWebRequest` you specify that by using standard `ftp://` protocol prefix and setting `EnableSsl = true` (what you do already).

See also [Does .NET FtpWebRequest Support both Implicit (FTPS) and explicit (FTPES)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842186/850848)