# Connecting to webapp with ftp in a release pipeline to download files

Tags: powershell, ftp, azure-powershell

Ive tried connecting to an ftp with the following powershell script:

```
#FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
$ftp = "ftp://XXX.com/" 
$user = 'UserName' 
$pass = 'Password'
$folder = 'FTP_Folder'
$target = "C:\Folder\Folder1\"

#SET CREDENTIALS
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
    while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
        $reader.ReadLine()
    }
    #$reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
}

#SET FOLDER PATH
$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$files = Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials

$files 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.txt"})){
    $source=$folderPath + $file  
    $destination = $target + $file 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file)

    #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
    $counter++
    $counter
    $source
}
```

But i keep getting 530 error (authentication error) when connecting. I know the username and password is working cause i've tested it in other ftp clients.
So, i think it might be a problem because the webapp demands a certain protocol, which isnt used in this script.

Ive been doing some research and i found something called Posh-SSH which might work.  But is there a way to modify my script instead? When im connecting with winscp i use FTP protocol with TLS/SSL implicit encryption to port 990.

**UPDATE: WORKS**
I made the following work:

```
#FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
$ftp = "ftp://waws-prod-xxx.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net" 
$user = 'xxxxx\xxxxx@email.com' 
$pass = '$FRnqxxpxxxxxxx'
$folder = 'site/wwwroot/wwwroot/images/uploaded'
$target = "C:\Folder\Folder1\"

#SET CREDENTIALS
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
    while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
        $reader.ReadLine()
    }
    #$reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
}

#SET FOLDER PATH
$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$files = Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials

Write-Host($files)


$files 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in ($files)){
    $source=$folderPath + $file  
    $destination = $target + $file 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file)

    #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
    $counter++
    $counter
    $source
}
```

I ended up adding a new credential to the web app, and changing sftp in hostname to ftp, and now it works. Using the credentials from webpublish file works too.
[image]

I also made WinSCP work and im able to download the full folder with children.

```
#FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
$ftp = "waws-prod-xxx-xxx.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net" 
$user = 'xxxxxx\xxxx@xxxxx.no' 
$pass = '$xxxxxxxxx'
$folder = 'site/wwwroot/wwwroot/images/uploaded/*'
$target = "C:\Folder\Folder1\*"

# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = $ftp
    UserName = $user
    Password = $pass 
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Download files
    $session.GetFiles($folder, $target).Check()
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FtpWebRequest` (nor any other built-in .NET FTP API) does not support implicit TLS/SSL encryption.
See [Does .NET FtpWebRequest Support both Implicit (FTPS) and explicit (FTPES)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842186/850848#44756668)

---

Posh-SSH is SSH/SFTP library. It has nothing to do with FTP.

---

And as you get an *"authentication error"*, I believe your problem is actually different. Double check your credentials. You are probably using wrong ones in your code.

Also, if WinSCP works for you, you can use [WinSCP .NET assembly from the PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell). WinSCP GUI can even [generate a code template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code), based on your working GUI session.

Comment: I did end up using WINSCP.